# Recover the content of a Firefox .part file?

Tags: firefox, zip, download

The question says it all, I have a `<filename>.zip.part` file in my Firefox download directory which is ~150MB and I'd like to recover its content.

The original file was a very large zip archive made of pictures and unfortunately it is now lost forever, so before redoing all the pictures again (illustrations for a book) I'd like to at least recover those that I already have in the .part file.

I tried to open it with software like Ark but without success.

Is there some trick to recover some of the file content?

**Edit:** I managed to recover some files using a Windows software called ZipRepair Pro. While searching, I saw there are many similar Windows software. So another way to put the original question would be: is there a similar software for Linux?

Comment: First, always work with a copy. You can try `zip -FF copyofdamagedzip --out maybefixed.zip` to try to get as much as possible while scanning from the beginning.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thanks for the reply, unfortunately the output is an empty file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been my experience that the `.part` files that you'll encounter when downloading content via Firefox are unusable until the download's complete. You can usually use these files to resume an interrupted download but not much more beyond that.

As far as tools to extract partial files on Linux that are similar to `ZipRepair Pro`. Beyond the method that @markPlotnick describes using `zip` like so:

```
$ zip -F copyofdamaged.zip --out maybefixed1.zip
$ unzip -l maybefixed1.zip
```

-or-

```
$ zip -FF copyofdamaged.zip --out maybefixed2.zip
$ unzip -l maybefixed2.zip
```

If neither of these work, you could try running this Windows application under Wine, [DiskInternals Zip Repair](http://www.diskinternals.com/zip-repair/). It's purported to run under [Wine just fine](https://superuser.com/a/32263/20568).

[image: ss #1]